# IIS C#.net web.config: Get matching "authorization" block line for current user?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, authorization, web-config

In an IIS 10 C#.NET setup, when a user is logged into a web application whose access control is done via web.config as seen below (logins controlled by AD), is it possible to retrieve the line from IIS which matched the current user?

```
<security>
  <authorization>
      <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
      <add accessType="Allow" roles="group1" />
      <add accessType="Allow" roles="group2" />
      <add accessType="Allow" users="CORP\user1" />
      <add accessType="Allow" users="EXT\user2" />
  </...
</...
```

The reason is that I would like to add more properties to users, so the app can tell between e.g. guest users, and admin users, etc.:

```
<security>
  <authorization>
      <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
      <add accessType="Allow" roles="group1" type="Full" />
      <add accessType="Allow" roles="group2" type="Guest" />
      <add accessType="Allow" users="CORP\user1" type="Full" />
      <add accessType="Allow" users="EXT\user2" type="Full" />
  </...
</...
```

I don't want to install a full-blown user management for various reasons, I want to keep it simple. No password management or user management in the app, this should all stay in Active Directory.

Or are there simple alternatives?

Comment: Microsoft designed an even simpler mechanism that won't meet your requirements, so you either switch to a full-blown framework, or develop your own.BTW, recommendation on frameworks is usually off topic.

Comment: I suggest that you can store users with different identities in the database, and obtain guest or administrator identities from the database when the user logs in. Or put the user identity in the response and obtain the identity from the response.

Comment: I would love to do that. However, our CI mandates that as soon as I store "user properties" (ie. anything but login name) in my own database instead of in AD, I am made subject of all kinds of security audits, rules, etc. which I *really* want to avoid. Let the CI manage users and their properties.
Perhaps defining an AD group "Guest users" and defining this group in a config file so that my app can tell the difference could also do the trick. Hm.